# Pointed my domain to new address, cannot now send or receive emails

Tags: domains, email, cpanel

I recently updated mydomain.com A record to point to a new ip and www.mydomain.com CNAME to a new address and now I can't send or receive emails. I have the mail.mydomain.com record still pointing to the original ip address, so that doesnt seem to be the problem.

My feeling is that this is due to my mx records now being incorrect, which as far as I can see from cpanel points to mydomain.com.

Comment: E-mail is always down to the MX record. But be aware that changing records in the cPanel may not be where you need to make your changes. Sometimes it is, sometimes it is not. People often get confused. You need to make changes using the control panel where your DNS records exist which is often the registrar. It can also be your host depending. Just make sure you know which one. I suspect you already do.

Answer (score 1):

If memory serves correctly when you change the CNAME and IP pointer for a domain to a new location, then on the **NEW** location you need to have/add/write a MX record in the zone file that points back to the previous mail host location if your going to have the previous location continue to handle mail activities.

Remember that the A record / CNAME record is checked FIRST by visiting systems for guidance on where to look for a MX record. So even though the old system is still setup to process e-mail requests for your domain, it is up to the NEW host to provide the roadmap to get back to the old server for mail functions.